# XHTML insert images into an unordered list?

Tags: image, list, xhtml, unordered

Does anyone know how to insert images into an unordered list using XHTML?

Comment: You mean dynamically? For that you'd need JavaScript. Be more specific.

Comment: Your question has been answered then. You may also want to read: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Answer (score 1):

This is valid XHTML

```
<ul>
  <li><img src="example.com/images/i.img" alt="ummm"/></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can add an image in a list like that, no prob. You must have something else happening in there. Can you post the ul construct (including the actual url etc. for the image)?